# How to integrate the following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve the following integral $$\int\frac{\sec^2(x)}{\sec^2(x)+a}dx$$ where $a$ is some positive constant. Thanks in advance.

Comment: tried $u= \tan x ? $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
$$
\dfrac{\sec^2(x)}{\sec^2(x) + a} = \dfrac{\sec^2(x) + a - a}{\sec^2(x) + a} = 1 - \dfrac{a}{\sec^2(x) + a}
$$
and $\sec^2(x) = 1 + \tan^2(x)$.

Comment: And how to solve the second part $\frac{a}{\sec^2(x)+a}?$ I am unable to do it

Comment: should I use $u=\tan(x)$ substitution after putting $\sec^2(x)=1+\tan^2(x)$?

Comment: Yes. And use partial fractions.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** 
\begin{align}
\frac{\sec^2 x}{\sec^2 x + a} = \frac{\sec^2 x}{1+a+\tan^2 x}
\end{align}
then $u = \tan x$.